# MySQL slow query log has some stuff added to my MySQL statements that isn't coming from my code, need help figuring out what it all means

Tags: php, mysql, performance

So my host contacted me and said my MySQL calls are taking up too much time on the MySQL server, and they sent me what they called a "MySQL slow query log" to look at to determine which ones to fix.  The main offender that seem to be eating up the most time is this:

```
SELECT parentmessages.* FROM userinfo, parentmessages WHERE parentmessages.parentid='11601' AND SLEEP(3) oRDeR BY 6 #' AND parentmessages.active='2' AND (userinfo.userid='') AND (parentmessages.userid = userinfo.userid)
```

However, I have no idea what the part below is.  It's not in my code at all, seems like it was added in by the server or something?  Or maybe just something added into the log?:

```
AND SLEEP(3) oRDeR BY 6 #'
```

The other main offender is basically the same query as above but with just this added in:

```
AND SLEEP(3)
```

When I run these MySQL statements as they are written (without the added chunks above) they run super fast: (Query took 0.0018 seconds.)  When I run them with the added chunks they take minutes and then timeout.  So I mean, certainly that would be the problem if they are running with that extra stuff added.  Just very confused where that extra stuff is coming from because it ain't coming from my code.

This is an old site without the updated PHP MySQLi functions (I know, I know, haven't had much time to work on it in years) so I'd be suspect of SQL injection or something like that but none of these queries are created with user-supplied data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your site is being attacked with [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

These extra/weird characters and commands would be entered by an attacker on one of your forms.

Find the page and code responsible for contributing to that query and employ adequte SQL injection prevention techniques such as preventing invalid characters from being entered into your forms.

If you are using PHP and MySQLi, then [mysqli::real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) will help.

Comment: No, if you're using mysqli then prepared statements will help! Adjust that and I'll give you the +1!

Comment: @miken32 erm.... are you saying that mysqli_real_escape_string() won't help? There's more than one way to skin a cat my friend...

Comment: There's more than one way to do SQL injection as well: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2784/php-mysqli/12843/escaping-strings#t=201703212350292025429

Comment: Hmm, if so I have a lot of work ahead of me, ug.  QUESTION: Does moving to MySQLi without using prepared statements / etc. add any security benefit at all?  Or would I need to go set everything up with prepared statements?  I have like... 100s of queries on this site and it's not a priority of mine nowadays so I don't think I'd go back and fix them all up as prepared statements.

Comment: @AndrewWhatever string escaping is better than nothing and will protect you from many types of injection. I was just trying to make this user aware that it's not a panacea and shouldn't be expected to protect you in all cases. Pardon my "chest beating!" ;)

Comment: @AndrewWhatever yes, ultimately both I and miken32 agree to disagree.  Just never trust user input. Add validation to your forms or escape your queries or go with prepared statements/stored procedures or a combination of all of these! Good luck.

Comment: Well looking hard I definitely see how these queries could be injected into (I did something sort of silly, to my credit this was many years ago), so I did a sort of quick stopgap closing of the holes.  We'll see if it stops the injections on these specific queries.  But to fix my whole site in a smarter way will be quite a big project.  100s and 100s of queries on the site.  Ug.

Comment: You must go through exactly one escaping mechanism -- either `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or some binding mechanism that does it under the covers.  Simply using the strings as they come from `$_GET` or `$_POST` is inviting a hacking fest.